# Is there a way to mount a Windows CIFS share and bypass the password prompt without a password file?

Tags: linux, windows, active-directory, mount

I'm trying to mount a Windows cifs share (shared by Windows) onto a CentOS box, per user.  Users are all in Active Directory.

So, every user who logs into their Linux box should be mounting the drive with their own credentials.

A solution I found was to mount using:

```
mount -t cifs //servername/mylogin /home/mylogin/windows -o uid=mylogin -o gid=groupname -o credentials=/home/mylogin/winpasswd
```

And for the /home/mylogin/winpasswd:

```
username=mylogin
domain=domainname
password=password_in_plain_text
```

However, I don't want to manually implement this for every Linux box and every user on every Linux box.  Also, I don't want users having their password in plain text anywhere. Is there a way to mount a Windows cifs share and bypass the password prompt without a password file?

Comment: My thoughts would be along the lines of Kerberos and automount : a Red Hat recipe appears here https://access.redhat.com/solutions/276503

Comment: That's where I went to as well, but I don't have a RedHat account to see the solution.  If you could kindly post the details here, you would be a hero.

Comment: Do you just want to give the password directly through the Mount command instead of saving it to a file?

Comment: No.  That's a step I want to cut out, because doing that multiple times for multiple shares is repetitive.

Comment: Never test this myself, but I think there are a few things you need to do on Windows side: 1. permission the share for "everyone" access; 2. Disable the setting "Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares"; 3. Enable "Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users". But needless to say, this make your windows server extremely vulnerable.

Comment: I do not want to grant any anonymous access for any reason.

Answer (score 1):

A way is to use `multiuser` cifs-mounts and `pam_cifscreds`. The Linux login password, and cifs password needs to match in order to use this solution.

Using `kerberos` authentication with `keyutils` configured for `cifs` and accordingly setup `pam` and/or `sssd` could also provide passwordless multiuser cifs-mounts.

Answer (score 0):

Same as HBruijn I'll say that automount is the solution.

Check http://www.electromech.info/rhce-linux-howtos-electromech-ahemdabad-gujarat/38-automounting-home-directories-with-nis-and-nfs.html

It's not the best source or tutorial I've seen, but i hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If the users are in AD and the Windows box is also enrolled in the domain then I suggest adding CentOS boxes to the domain as well and employing kerberos/gssapi for single sign on.

sssd is capable of joining the AD and I am using such a setup myself.